# sqlite исчезновение данных

Tags: python, sqlite

1. Исходный (.txt) файл весит ~1ГБ.
2. Запускаю скрипт с исходным файлом, создаётся БД с таблицей и весит ~300МБ.
3. Открываю таблицу в SQlite Studio, данные исчезают, БД начинает весить ~2КБ.
4. Также написал отдельно скрипт, который делает выборку из базы, проделал первые два пункта, пытаюсь выбрать хоть что - то, не выбирается.

Если работаю с исходными файлами ~2МБ, всё хорошо

Что это может быть ?

Comment: открываете в SQlite Studio во время сессии в Python?

Comment: *Открываю таблицу в SQlite Studio, данные исчезают, БД начинает весить ~2КБ.* Попробуйте явно правами файловой системы запретить удаление файла БД... для начала.

Comment: 1Гб - файлы надо уже БД использовать. SQlite  -  это обычный текстовый файл с хорошей имитацией сиквел - запросов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У всех прошу прощения, проблема решена, просто файл исходный (который я парсил) был с ошибками и приложение крашилось во время парсинга, а commit в базу я делал не на каждом шаге цикла, а как полагается, после всего цикла, поэтому в базе ничего и не было. Потом, когда подебажил, понял, до последнего отказывался в это верить. Всем спасибо за ответы, всё учту!